# Azure AD application preconsent not working

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

(Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508940/multi-tenant-application-with-pre-consent-cannot-call-graph-api/39515269#39515269))

I have an application that should be automatically usable for all customer tenants, and therefore tried [this tutorial](https://github.com/PartnerCenterSamples/Commerce-API-DotNet/blob/83f46c508ca8d4434f9b4d8b72dc5fc5467631d4/Documentation/PreConsent.md) to enable `preconsent`.

After doing the Powershell commands and getting again the application, I can see that it is enabled:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $graphResponse.value.recordConsentConditions
SilentConsentForPartnerManagedApp
```

However, when creating a new tenant(or using an existing one) and trying to access Microsoft Graph's /users call, I get a 500 error until I navigate to [https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&prompt=admin_consent](https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7B0%7D&prompt=admin_consent) (with `{0}` being the `cliendId` of the app), sign in as an admin and accept the delegation.

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a contact with Microsoft support, this is a bug on their side. They told me yesterday that the engineer team acknowledged it. It will be fixed.

Comment: This is not a bug, but a missing feature that we are working on.  It's one of the gaps that is called out in this blog:  https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph

Answer (score 0):

In order to query the MS Graph, your app will need to be granted the appropriate permissions by an end user or by an administrator of the tenant.  Usually the best way to acquire consent from an administrator is by using the `prompt=admin_consent` parameter, as you've done above.

If for some reason you must do so via powershell, you can create an [`oAuth2PermissionGrant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#oauth2permissiongrant-entity) object using a `consentType` of `AllPrincipals`.

Personally I wouldn't recommend using the `recordConsentConditions` property.  It's only there for legacy reasons - I don't even know what it does.

Comment: I cannot ask for consent to all clients, the goal was automation, hence the use of preconsent. The legacy way is still supported according to their doc, I also tried another way: Add the corresponding Service Principal for the application to the AdminAgents Security Group . No results either: as stated in my answer, it appears my cas is a Microsoft-side bug.