# Microsoft Graph Admin on Behalf (Pre-Consent) can't obtain a token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have seen at this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

that Microsoft Graph as a gap related with (Partner admin on behalf of capability (for resellers and syndicators)).

Also, I have seen this other stackoverflow question: [Azure AD application preconsent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516468/azure-ad-application-preconsent-not-working), refering to a bug fix.

Today I have tried the Pre-Consent with the Microsoft Graph API but I can't obtain a token.

Is this something that is not yet supported?
What alternatives do I have to call the Microsoft Graph API with admin on behalf?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes - unfortunately this is still not supported.  However it is hopefully something we'll have available *very* soon. I'll update this post when it's available.