# Is there any way possible to pre-approve application permissions for graph api without having to do adminconsent oauth?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

Is there a way to let an application call graph api with admin privileges without having the admin to go through oauth?

I looked at [Multi-tenant application with pre-consent cannot call graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508940/multi-tenant-application-with-pre-consent-cannot-call-graph-api) but I don't have powershell to do that. Is there an API I can interact myself without that powershell script to pre-approve application's access rights?

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't provide additional API as your hypothetical scenario. Normally, we need to run the admin-consent once then the end user no need to apply the consent again.

[admin consent docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

Comment: What about the process described there https://github.com/PartnerCenterSamples/Commerce-API-DotNet/blob/83f46c508ca8d4434f9b4d8b72dc5fc5467631d4/Documentation/PreConsent.md ?